# How to correct files with mixed encodings?

Tags: emacs, utf-8

Given a corrupted file with mixed encoding (e.g. utf-8 and latin-1), how do I configure Emacs to "project" all its symbols to a single encoding (e.g. utf-8) when saving the file?

I did the following function to automatize some of the cleaning, but I would guess I could find somewhere the information to map the symbol "é" in one encoding to "é" in utf-8 somewhere in order to improve this function (or that somebody already wrote such a function).

```
  (defun jyby/cleanToUTF ()
    "Cleaning to UTF"
    (interactive)
    (progn
         (save-excursion (replace-regexp "अ" ""))
         (save-excursion (replace-regexp "आ" ""))
         (save-excursion (replace-regexp "ॆ" ""))
       )
  )

  (global-unset-key [f11])
  (global-set-key [f11] 'jyby/cleanToUTF)
```

---

I have many files "corrupted" with mixed encoding (due to copy pasting from a browser with an ill font configuration), generating the error below. I sometime clean them by hand by searching and replacing for each problematic symbol by either "" or the appropriate character, or more quickly specifying "utf-8-unix" as the encoding (which will prompt the same message next time I edit and save the file). It has become an issue as in any such corrupted file any accentuated character is replaced by a sequence which *doubles* in size at each save, ending up doubling the size of the file. I am using GNU Emacs 24.2.1

```
These default coding systems were tried to encode text
in the buffer `test_accents.org':
(utf-8-unix (30 . 4194182) (33 . 4194182) (34 . 4194182) (37
. 4194182) (40 . 4194181) (41 . 4194182) (42 . 4194182) (45
. 4194182) (48 . 4194182) (49 . 4194182) (52 . 4194182))
However, each of them encountered characters it couldn't encode:
utf-8-unix cannot encode these:           ...

Click on a character (or switch to this window by `C-x o'
and select the characters by RET) to jump to the place it appears,
where `C-u C-x =' will give information about it.

Select one of the safe coding systems listed below,
or cancel the writing with C-g and edit the buffer
to remove or modify the problematic characters,
or specify any other coding system (and risk losing
the problematic characters).

raw-text emacs-mule no-conversion
```

Comment: But is there a way to convert it automatically? Currently I select each offending character by hand, and perform a search and replace to delete it in the whole document. I plan to write a lisp function to automatize this, but I don't know how to automatize the list of offending characters (plus I would hope to do something more clever, such as é -> e, or something smarter projecting to accentuated characthers in utf-8...)

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled with this in emacs many times.  When I have a file that was messed up, e.g. in raw-text-unix mode, and save as utf-8, emacs complains even about text that is already clean utf-8.  I haven't found a way to get it to only complain about non-utf-8.

I just found a reasonable semi-automated approach using recode:

```
f=mixed-file
recode -f ..utf-8 $f > /tmp/recode.out
diff $f recode.out | cat -vt

# manually fix lines of text that can't be converted to utf-8 in $f,
# and re-run recode and diff until the output diff is empty.
```

One helpful tool along the way is http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=342+200+224&mode=obytes

Then I just re-open the file in emacs, and it is recognized as clean unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to maybe get you started:

```lisp
(put 'eof-error 'error-conditions '(error eof-error))
(put 'eof-error 'error-message "End of stream")
(put 'bad-byte 'error-conditions '(error bad-byte))
(put 'bad-byte 'error-message "Not a UTF-8 byte")

(defclass stream ()
  ((bytes :initarg :bytes :accessor bytes-of)
   (position :initform 0 :accessor position-of)))

(defun logbitp (byte bit) (not (zerop (logand byte (ash 1 bit)))))

(defmethod read-byte ((this stream) &optional eof-error eof)
  (with-slots (bytes position) this
    (if (< position (length bytes))
        (prog1 (aref bytes position) (incf position))
      (if eof-error (signal eof-error (list position)) eof))))

(defmethod unread-byte ((this stream))
  (when (> (position-of this) 0) (decf (position-of this))))

(defun read-utf8-char (stream)
  (let ((byte (read-byte stream 'eof-error)))
    (if (not (logbitp byte 7)) byte
      (let ((numbytes
             (cond
              ((not (logbitp byte 5))
               (setf byte (logand #2r11111 byte)) 1)
              ((not (logbitp byte 4))
               (setf byte (logand #2r1111 byte)) 2)
              ((not (logbitp byte 3))
               (setf byte (logand #2r111 byte)) 3))))
        (dotimes (b numbytes byte)
          (let ((next-byte (read-byte stream 'eof-error)))
            (if (and (logbitp next-byte 7) (not (logbitp next-byte 6)))
                (setf byte (logior (ash byte 6) (logand next-byte #2r111111)))
              (signal 'bad-byte (list next-byte)))))
        (signal 'bad-byte (list byte))))))

(defun load-corrupt-file (file)
  (interactive "fFile to load: ")
  (with-temp-buffer
    (set-buffer-multibyte nil)
    (insert-file-literally file)
    (with-output-to-string
      (set-buffer-multibyte t)
      (loop with stream = (make-instance 'stream :bytes (buffer-string))
            for next-char =
            (condition-case err
                (read-utf8-char stream)
              (bad-byte (message "Fix this byte %d" (cdr err)))
              (eof-error nil))
            while next-char
            do (write-char next-char)))))
```

What this code does - it loads a file with no conversion and tries to read it as if it was encoded using UTF-8, once it encounters a byte that doesn't seem like it belongs to UTF-8, it errors, and you need to handle it somehow, it's where `"Fix this byte"` message is). But you would need to be inventive about how you fixing it...

Comment: Looks interesting - thanks! But when I put that in a buffer and evaluate it I get "eval-region: Symbol's function definition is void: defclass", and google doesn't understand that, and I don't understand EIEIO which seems related.  I'm using GNU Emacs 23.3.1 on ubuntu precise